# Storing user data in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to find a way to store data based on a user's move (input).

For example, they can pick up a ball multiple times, and that gets added to their inventory (data storage).

Any ideas as to how I could do this and be able to update the data, based on how many times it is picked up?

Thanks

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 2):

Not enough details were provided, and therefore am giving you the best answer possible after interpreting your question.

You can use a dictionary to store all the items as the key, and the number of times the user picked that item up as a value.

```
data = {"ball": 0, "bat": 0, "helmet":0}

answer = input("What would you like to pick up? (ball, bat, or a helmet?)")
if answer in data:
    data[answer] += 1
else:
    data[answer] = 1
```

This was a simple example, and I had pre-popualated the dictionary. In your program you will have to check if the item exists or not, and then increment like I did. Hope this helped.